# Eclipse plugin to compare zip files

Tags: eclipse, zip

In projects I work on occasionally files are stored in an archive.  Editing things in eclipse is straight forward one installed the [Eclipse Zip Editor Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zipeditor/).  However, I can't compare the changes made in the zipfile using the standard Team->compare functionality.  Are there any tricks to accomplish this within eclipse?

Comment: See http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91839415.html

Comment: @Benj cool link, didn't know eclipse could do that.  Seems like the link is just for JARs though, any chance you've seen anything that does the same for .zip archives?

Comment: Eclipse has native compare support for zip and jars.  Use the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has native comparison support for .zip archives and .jar files.  Select the two files you wish to compare, then right-click on one of them and choose `Compare With > Each Other`.